# What is the proper way to type for Array with a single NonNullable element?

Tags: typescript

I want the proper type for Array with a single NonNullable element

```
[] //error
[null] //error
[undefined] //error
[5] // good
[1, 2] // error
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have [`strictNullChecks` enabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks), and using a type of `[number]` should ensure that only `[5]` will pass the type check:

```
type MyArray = [number];

const arr1: MyArray = []; //error
const arr2: MyArray = [null]; //error
const arr3: MyArray = [undefined]; //error
const arr4: MyArray = [5]; // good
const arr5: MyArray = [1, 2]; // error
```

TypeScript will throw an error on arrays that are not of a single length and do not contain a number in the single element there in:

[image: Example output from TypeScript playground]

See example on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEUC8UDaA7ArgLYBGEiAugNwBQ1AxgPa4DOwUKyAjAFywLJpMOKlAD0osogaJ6TVu2QAmXnCSp0WPPgA22keMnTZLNh0QBmFf3VDs+XABMIAMwCWuCA-0TkRxiYVEABYrNUFNAFZvKABzBgYHY3kzCNCBDRxOABooRWjDGSA).

---

Update: if you want to use generics so that you can specify the type of the element in the array, you can just use `type MyArray<T> = [T];`:

```
type MyArray<T> = [T];

const arr1: MyArray<number> = []; //error
const arr2: MyArray<number> = [null]; //error
const arr3: MyArray<number> = [undefined]; //error
const arr4: MyArray<number> = [1, 2]; // error
const arr5: MyArray<string> = [5]; // error

const arr6: MyArray<number> = [5]; // good
const arr7: MyArray<string> = ['lorem']; // good
const arr8: MyArray<boolean> = [true]; // good
```

Comment: And if it's not required to be a number, I think he will have to go with `[string | number | boolean | symbol | object]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, so, for generic way,  `type MyArray = [<T>(a: T)];` will be fine?

Comment: @Functor No. Your type is expecting a function in the array. This should suffice: `type MyArray<T> = [T];`